# Ubuntu does not remember my microsoft account

Tags: ubuntu, accounts, microsoft-teams

My computer (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS), does not remember my business Microsoft account and I need to Login and 2FA each time.

Is there a way to remember my Microsoft account?

Comment: I'm assuming this is about Teams only?

Comment: my account is a business microsoft one. So what-ever is related to that. E.g. vpn software requires microsoft authentication